# How to define some shortcut-keys for dmenu?

Tags: arch-linux, i3, tiling-wm, dmenu

When using `dmenu` to launch applications, it supports Ctrl+N and Ctrl+P to choose next one and previous one. How can I define Ctrl+H and Ctrl+L to function same to choose?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily create a patch for `dmenu.c` that added the required keys to the stanza at [line 316](https://git.suckless.org/dmenu/tree/dmenu.c#n316):

```
        case XK_n: ksym = XK_Down;      break;
        case XK_p: ksym = XK_Up;        break;
+       case XK_H: ksym = XK_Down;      break;
+       case XK_L: ksym = XK_Up;        break;
```

Comment: you....really fantastic...let me research it...